# escaping effect Monad vs. not escaping

Tags: scala, scalaz

Are these two functions different in any way?

```
case class DFStorage(private var cache: Map[String, DataFrame] = Map()) {

  def tryLoad(job: Job): Kleisli[IO, MakeContext, \/[List[String], Unit]] = {
    if(!cache.contains(job.id)) {
      job.tryLoad.map(_.map(df => add(job, df)))
    } else {
      IO(().right[List[String]]).liftKleisli
    }
  }


  def tryLoad(job: Job): Kleisli[IO, MakeContext, \/[List[String], Unit]] = {
    Kleisli({makeContext: MakeContext =>
      if(!cache.contains(job.id)) {
        IO {
          job.tryLoad.run(makeContext).unsafePerformIO().map(df => add(job, df))
        }
      } else {
        IO(().right[List[String]])
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are supposed to call `unsafePerformIO` as the **final** side effect in your program (e.g. in your main function), but in this case it may result in the same thing given that you are "unwrapping" the value in the IO monad and then wrapping a transformation of that value. As you can see this unwrapping and transformation of the value may be the same process that `IO.map` does.

`unsafePerformIO` is used to force the execution of the side effects represented by the IO value. In Haskell your program must be something of type IO and Haskell runs it (`main` must have type IO). But in Scala the main function can do anything, so you must execute the IO at that point.

Comment: I'll take that as an "mostly no".